# Windows beforeunload gives alert message even though there is no pending changes to save

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using the following  jQuery to alert user when they navigates  away from given page without clicking save/update button. It works as expected but it gives the alert message even though there is not any pending changes left to save. It alert the user when they saved all the changes they made and try to navigates away from the page. I want it to alert only if they didn't save their changes.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var unsaved = false;
            $(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
                if (unsaved) {
                    return "You have made some changes. Save your pending changes before existing the page";
                }
            });
            // Monitor dynamic inputs
            $(document).on('change', ':input', function () { 
                unsaved = true;
            });          
        })
```

Comment: Show us where you set `unsaved` to false after a save.

Comment: I used saved logic on aspx.cs file, how do we set unsaved to false on .cs file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you set unsaved to false after a save happened. Try the following code, it might works

```
        $(document).ready(function () { 
            $(document).on('change', ':input', function (e) {
                $(this).addClass('changed-input');
            });

            $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
                if ($('.changed-input').length) {
                    return 'You haven\'t saved the changes you made.';
                }
            });
        })
```

**Reference:** [link](http://www.bitnative.com/2013/08/19/warn-users-of-unsaved-changes-with-jquery/)

Comment: The link you provided is very helpful for me.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Coz you don't have else in your condition... 
if you want to disable the alert if unsave is false,

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
            return isSave();
        });

function isSave() {
    if (unsaved) {
        return "You have made some changes. Save your pending changes before existing the page";
    }
    else {
        window.beforeunload = null;
        window.unbind();
    }
}
```